# How to obtain innerHTML of an active li link?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, meteor

I want to store the innerHTML of an active menu item to display it as a title for my page. The title HTML is {{pageTitle}}, in the "container" template.

here is my (cleaned) HTML

```
<template name="container">
   {{pageTitle}
   {{ > SideMenu}}
</template>

<template name="SideMenu">
    <ul id="menu-items" class="nav nav-stacked nav-pills">
        <li id="menu-item-simple" class="">
            <a href="#">
                menuItem1
            </a>
        </li>
        <li id="menu-item-simple" class="">
            <a href="#">
                menuItem2
            </a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</template>
```

I created an helper to return the string

```
Template.container.helpers({
"pageTitle":function(){
    return Session.get("pageTitle");
}
});
```

And an event to set the string to its correct value when a menu item is clicked

```
Template.SideMenu.events({
    "click #menu-items":function(e,t){
        var activeItem = $(this).find("li.active")
        Session.set ("pageTitle",activeItem.children("a").innerHTML);
        console.log (activeItem.children("a").innerHTML);
    }
});
```

The console returns "undefined". I don't get what I am doing wrong and since I'm just beginning, I also wanted to know if I'm going the right way.

Comment: Your html has duplicate ID elements `id="menu-item-simple"` Can you log the `activeItem` in console and check?

Comment: both "activeItem.id" and "activeItem.class" return "undefined" when logged in the console. I'm lost. Shouldn't it be working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was here:

```
var activeItem = $(this).find("li.active")
```

it should have been

```
var activeItem = $(t.find("li.active"))
```

I don't get why a simple this.find("li.active") didn't work, as Shaunak D suggested

Thanks for your help!

**EDIT:**

It seems that when the event "click #menu-items" is raised the active li found is the previous one. Do you guys know what event I should hook to display the currently active link?

**EDIT ANSWER**

```
Session.set ("pageTitle",$(e.target).text());
```

Comment: Just to complete your last line of code if you want to obtain jquery element, I'd suggest you to directly write t.$('li.active'); instead of $(t.find(...)) As described here: http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/template_$

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried ?

```
Session.set ("pageTitle",activeItem.children("a").text());
```

[jquery text()](http://api.jquery.com/text/)

Comment: The console returns  "empty string" when I use text()

Comment: I guess : `$(this).find("li.active")` doesn't exit.

Comment: Try `t.find(..` or `this.find(..`

Comment: "TypeError: t.find is not a function". Same with this.find(.. . It finally worked with $(t.find("li.active")) . Lol, I still don't get why